# MySQL Return everything if a letter or word is matched?

Tags: php, mysql, regex

This is what I am using right now:

```
SELECT * FROM title where title.posttitle LIKE '%$Search%'
```

If someone searches for `How to make Apple Pie` it returns the right thing.

If someone searches for `make Apple Pie` it returns nothing for some reason.

How can I make it so if any letter or word matches it returns the record?

Comment: @AvinashRaj Search is Text from a input

Comment: You need to: a) Provide some example results as well as just queries. b) Provide some things you've tried doing.

Comment: try after converting column name & search criteria either uppercase or lowercase.

Comment: If `$search = 'How to make Apple Pie'` works, then `$search = 'make Apple Pie'` does, too. So if it doesn't, then $search must contain something else. Additional blanks maybe?

Comment: If you are viewing the contents of `$search` in a browser only one whitespace will be displayed. Try outputting the exact query you are running and exact it directly on the DB.

Answer (score 0):

If the posttitle contains exactly the $Search value will produce a response. In my point of view searching exactly for a string holding multiple words is not the best practice.
I would break the string into words (example using javascript)

```
var string = "my sample sentence";
var words = str.split(" ");
```

and then i would search if contains those words

```
SELECT * FROM title where (title.posttitle LIKE '%words[0]%') AND (title.posttitle LIKE '%words[1]%') ...etc
```

storing data in one format to your db would also help the search (all lowercase or uppercase)

Comment: You can always use a case-insensitive collation and store the data as entered.